# Jquery animate function not moving image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm trying to move an image and that's about it. I cant seem to figure out why its giving my problems. The idea is to have the image go in a square pattern all while rotating a set of images. Ill figure out that part but right now I cant get the image to animate at all.

HTML:

```
  <body>
    <h1>Assignment 1</h1>
    <hr>

    <img id="img_num" src="images/img_num1.png" alt="Image."/>

    <hr>
    <a href="index.html">PAGE 1 | </a>
    <a href="page2.html">PAGE 2</a>

    <footer>Name | Student #</footer>
  </body>
```

JS:

```
$(window).onload(function(event)
{   
    while(true)
    {   
         $('#img_num').animate(
          {"left": "+=50px"},
          "slow");
    }    
});
```

CSS:

```
#img_num {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: What is purpose of `while` loop?

Comment: Ill eventually be making the image do a square and i want that done repeatedly.

Comment: `while` could block UI from reaching `.animate()` function. You could alternatively call `.animate()` recursively.

Comment: OH! That makes sense. Ya it was freezing before and I was so confused. That must be why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.onload` is not a jQuery method, use `.load()`; also, `while` loop does not appear to be necessary

```js
$(window).load(function(event) {
  //  while(true)
  //  {   
  $('#img_num').animate({
      "left": "+=50px"
    },
    "slow");
  //  }    
});
```

```css
#img_num {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<body>
  <h1>Assignment 1</h1>
  <hr>

  <img id="img_num" src="http://placehold.it/300" alt="Image." />

  <hr>
  <a href="index.html">PAGE 1 | </a>
  <a href="page2.html">PAGE 2</a>

  <footer>Name | Student #</footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Jquery?

Try this Jquery... it will move it out of the screen

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#img_num').animate({
    "left": $(window).width()
  },1000);

})
```